# Where is the bottleneck in this code?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, gcc, x86

I have the following tight loop that makes up the serial bottle neck of my code. Ideally I would parallelize the function that calls this but that is not possible.

```
//n is about 60
for (int k = 0;k < n;k++) 
{
    double fone = z[k*n+i+1];
    double fzer = z[k*n+i];
    z[k*n+i+1]= s*fzer+c*fone;
    z[k*n+i] = c*fzer-s*fone;
}
```

Are there any optimizations that can be made such as vectorization or some evil inline that can help this code?

I am looking into finding eigen solutions of tridiagonal matrices. http://www.cimat.mx/~posada/OptDoglegGraph/DocLogisticDogleg/projects/adjustedrecipes/tqli.cpp.html

Comment: Non-sequential memory access. Period.

Comment: What is `i`? Is there a loop involving it?

Comment: Do you have an outer loop over `i`?

Comment: Would you mind coming up with self-contained example we can compile and experiment with?

Comment: Try allocating fone and fzer outside of the loop, then setting them inside the loop. Most likely they will compile into two push and then pop instructions. You could also use a pointer to store the two array indices so you don't have to calculate k*n+i and k*n+i+1 twice every time.

Comment: Can we get some high-level description of what the code is supposed to do? What problem is it solving?

Comment: @jalf My problem reduced to a bottleneck in a numerical recipe.

Comment: @Mikhail: Did you use a profiler to determine that _this_ is indeed your bottleneck?

Comment: @stefan yes, I used callgrind... I just don't know how to fix it and I am running up against the amdahl limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**: Change the memory layout of your matrix from row-major order to column-major order.

**Long answer**:
It seems you are accessing the (i)th and (i+1)th column of a matrix stored in row-major order - probably a big matrix that doesn't as a whole fit into CPU cache. Basically, on every loop iteration the CPU has to wait for RAM (in the order of hundred cycles). After a few iteraterations, theoretically, the address prediction should kick in and the CPU should speculatively load the data items even before the loop acesses them. That should help with RAM latency. But that still leaves the problem that the code uses the memory bus inefficiently: CPU and memory never exchange single bytes, only cache-lines (64 bytes on current processors). Of every 64 byte cache-line loaded and stored your code only touches 16 bytes (or a quarter).

Transposing the matrix and accessing it in native major order would increase memory bus utilization four-fold. Since that is probably the bottle-neck of your code, you can expect a speedup of about the same order.

Whether it is worth it, depends on the rest of your algorithm. Other parts may of course suffer because of the changed memory layout.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on "Of every 64 byte cache-line loaded and stored your code only touches 16 bytes (or a quarter)." I don't understand why only 16 bytes touch the memory bus...

Comment: Well, during a memory transaction, the CPU never loads or stores anything less than a cache-line (64 bytes). Your code loads and stores 16 consecutive bytes: z[k*n+i], z[k*n+i+1]. However, the CPU doesn't load 16 bytes, it loads 64 bytes - the particular cache-line that contains the data. Of these 64 bytes, 48 are loaded and stored in vein. They take up valuable bus-resources, but your code cannot take advantage.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you are rotating something (or rather, lots of things, by the same angle (s being a sin, c being a cos))?

Counting backwards is always good fun and cuts out variable comparison for each iteration, and should work here. Making the counter the index might save a bit of time also (cuts out a bit of arithmetic, as said by others).

```
for (int k = (n-1) * n + i; k >= 0; k -= n)
{
    double fone=z[k+1];
    double fzer=z[k];
    z[k+1]=s*fzer+c*fone;
    z[k]  =c*fzer-s*fone;
}
```

Nothing dramatic here, but it looks tidier if nothing else.

Comment: I tried the run and I didn't notice much of a difference. By the way I am working on finding the eigen values of a tridiagonal matrix system.

Answer (score 1):

As first move i'd cache pointers in this loop:

```
//n is about 60
double *cur_z = &z[0*n+i]
for (int k = 0;k < n;k++) 
{
    double fone = *(cur_z+1);
    double fzer = *cur_z;
    *(cur_z+1)= s*fzer+c*fone;
    *cur_z = c*fzer-s*fone;
    cur_z += n;
}
```

Second, i think its better to make templatized version of this function. As a result, you can get good perfomance benefit if your matrix holds **integer** values (since FPU operations are slower).

Comment: What do you mean by templatized version, do you mean that I should unroll the entire for loop (I might be able to do that...)? Also what do you mean by integers.

Comment: Your matrix holds **double** values. If you can manage to deal without **double**-s its will work faster